# Creating a delayed blur effect?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, effects

I would like to recreate an effect similar to that seen at this timestamp in the following video of Zelda: Majora's Mask 3d: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-FoQ1XNoGM&t=462

I believe this was accomplished by having each frame fade slowly away (and travel northeast) after it played.

Is there any simple way to achieve this in Blender? I'd prefer this to be accomplished in the VSE, without any custom scripts (if possible).

Comment: There's probably a way you could import the video into the compositor, blur a delayed one, and mix it with the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have an elegant solution but it seems to work. Instead of fading a frame, I just use 8 or more strips with the same image sequence and move them each one frame to the right.

Each of the strips (except the bottom one) gets a transform strip. There I lower the opacity and move the strip a bit with the position fields.

You might need to use a gaussian blur strip, too.

It looks a bit better if the Blend type is set to 'add'

[image: stairs]

Comment: Could you share your .blend file? I'm extremely unfamiliar with the VSE, and so don't completely follow.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50755 Here it is. Blender is really bad for trying stuff out without learning the background. Just like an airplane cockpit. Bumpy road ahead.

Comment: Did some testing with this method. Works extremely well and gives me an effect extremely similar to what I'm going for, except for the excessive visibility of the transformed frames. That's a issue for another question, though. Thank you! :-)